# Snakemake: how to use one integer from list each call as input to script?

Tags: r, python-3.x, snakemake

I'm trying to practice writing workflows in snakemake.

The contents of my Snakefile:

```
configfile: "config.yaml"

rule get_col:
  input:
   expand("data/{file}.csv",file=config["datname"])
  output:
   expand("output/{file}_col{param}.csv",file=config["datname"],param=config["cols"])
  params:
   col=config["cols"]
  script:
   "scripts/getCols.R"
```

The contents of config.yaml:

```
cols:
  [2,4]
datname:
  "GSE3790_expression_data"
```

My R script:

```
getCols=function(input,output,col) {
  dat=read.csv(input)
  dat=dat[,col]
  write.csv(dat,output,row.names=F)
}

getCols(snakemake@input[[1]],snakemake@output[[1]],snakemake@params[['col']])
```

It seems like both columns are being called at once. **What I'm trying to accomplish is one column being called from the list per output file.**

Since the second output never gets a chance to be created (both columns are used to create first output), snakemake throws an error:

```
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 3 of /Users/rebecca/Desktop/snakemake-tutorial/practice/Snakefile:
Job completed successfully, but some output files are missing.
```

On a slightly unrelated note, I thought I could write the input as:
'"data/{file}.csv"'
But that returns:

```
WildcardError in line 4 of /Users/rebecca/Desktop/snakemake-tutorial/practice/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'file'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to run your Rscript twice per file, once for every value of `col`. In this case, the rule needs to be called twice as well.
The use of `expand` is also a bit too much here, in my opinion. `expand` fills your wildcards with all possible values and returns a list of the resulting files. So the output for this rule would be all possible combinations between `files` and `cols`, which the simple script can not create in one run.
This is also the reason why `file` can not be inferred from the output - it gets expanded there.

Instead, try writing your rule easier for just one file and column and expand on the resulting output, in a rule which needs this output as an input. If you generated the final output of your workflow, put it as input in a `rule all` to tell the workflow what the ultimate goal is.

```
rule all:
  input:
    expand("output/{file}_col{param}.csv",
    file=config["datname"], param=config["cols"])

rule get_col:
  input:
    "data/{file}.csv"
  output:
    "output/{file}_col{param}.csv"
  params:
    col=lambda wc: wc.param
  script:
    "scripts/getCols.R"
```

Snakemake will infer from `rule all` (or any other rule to further use the output) what needs to be done and will call the `rule get_col` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would you mind elaborating on the use of lambda wc (wildcard)? It's not clear to me when a variable needs to defined as being a wildcard object, versus just referencing it directly (e.g. col={param} vs. col=labda wc: wc.param).

Comment: One note to add: I needed to write 'col=lambda wc: wc.param' as 'col=lambda wc: int(wc.param)' for the code to run in R.

Comment: In my version, the lambda function is indeed not needed. Basically, use it if you want to modulate the wildcard in any way, just as you did with int().